# Cannot resolve constructor and method for reason I don't know

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

```
public void openNumbers (View view) {
        Intent numbers = new Intent(this, NumbersActivity.class);
        startActivity(numbers);
    }
```

Is there something wrong with these lines of code??? I;ve got red line under the (this, NumbersActivity.class); and it says cannot resolve constuctor 'Intent(......)' and red text startActivity saying cannot re[enter image description here][1]solve method 'startActivity(android.content.Intent)'

**I'm a totally new to this**

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/tan_background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.miwok.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/numbers"
        style="@style/CategoryStyle"
        android:background="@color/category_numbers"
        android:text="@string/category_numbers"
        android:onClick="openNumbers"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/family"
        style="@style/CategoryStyle"
        android:background="@color/category_family"
        android:text="@string/category_family" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/colors"
        style="@style/CategoryStyle"
        android:background="@color/category_colors"
        android:text="@string/category_colors" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phrases"
        style="@style/CategoryStyle"
        android:background="@color/category_phrases"
        android:text="@string/category_phrases" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.android.miwok;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set the content of the activity to use the activity_main.xml layout file
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void openNumbers (View view) {
        Intent numbers = new Intent(this, NumbersActivity.class);
        startActivity(numbers);
    }
}
```

AndroidManidest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.miwok">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".NumbersActivity" >

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".PhrasesActivity" >

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".FamilyActivity" >

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ColorsActivity">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**I know what is the error already! The error is there are no errors... although AS is showing red font but when i adb the app on my phone its just fine even with red font IDK WHY**

**I know what is the error already! The error is there are no errors... although AS is showing red font but when i adb the app on my phone its just fine even with red font IDK WHY**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are starting activity from `onClick()` method, so when building an `Intent` you have to use the `Context` of current `Activity`.

**Use:**

```
Intent numbers = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NumbersActivity.class);
```

**Instead of:**

```
Intent numbers = new Intent(this, NumbersActivity.class);
```

**FYI,** you have to import `android.content.Intent` to use `Intent`.

Finally, `Clean` your project and `Build` again. I hope your problem will be resolved.

Comment: but now the CURRENT_ACTIVITY and the startActivity are in red font ;(

Comment: Here `CURRENT_ACTIVITY`  means your activity from where you are trying to start another activity. If its name `MainActivity` then use `Intent numbers = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NumbersActivity.class); ` Hope you  understand!

Comment: I totally understand but why ANDROID STUDIO giving me error still. I've been searching for solution for 4 hours because of this line of code.

Comment: have you added `import android.content.Intent;` in your code?

Comment: Your layout and java code seems perfect. Can you please post an screenshot of errors?

Comment: clean your project and build again. I hope your problem will be solved. I have tried your code in my pc and its working fine.

Comment: If my answer seems useful, I hope you will give an up-vote too :)

Comment: You have enough points to upvote. It requires 15 Reputation and you have 21. I think you can do this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up

Answer (score 1):

Replace this with YourClassName.this then your problem will be solved

Answer (score 1):

**replece this with your code**

```
public void openNumbers (View view) {
    Intent numbers = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NumbersActivity.class);
    startActivity(numbers);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No problem with using
Intent numbers = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NumbersActivity.class);
Intent numbers = new Intent(this, NumbersActivity.class);

please clean the project and rebuild and see if problem still exist or not,i think that will go away..

and if error will come studio will show you some message for the same kindly read that message and post it for helping the same..

Answer (score 0):

You just declare method "openNumbers" outside the onCreate method in activity

```
public void openNumbers (View view) {
    Intent numbers = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NumbersActivity.class);
    startActivity(numbers);
}
```